# Add style to a specific class

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a three divs that has same classes assigned to it. What I want to do is to apply a separate style to the first div and different to other two.

```
   <div class="news_post">...</div>
<div class="news_post">...</div>
<div class="news_post">...</div>
```

Any suggestions on what is the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kebip/1/edit)

```
.news_post:first-child {
  background: red;
}

.news_post {
  background: green;
}
```

If you want to customize any element in future

```
.news_post:nth-child(2) { // 2 represents the position
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.news_post:nth-child(1)
{
   background:#ff0000;
}

.news_post:nth-child(2)
{
   background:blue;
}

.news_post:nth-child(3)
{
   background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pseudo Element Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

[:nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

[:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)

[:last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

If you only want to apply different style on `First Div` Try this :

```
.news_post{
    background-color:black;
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
}
.news_post:first-child
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24SSd/)

If you want to apply different-different style on all three divs, Try this :

```
.news_post{
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
}
.news_post:nth-child(1)
{
   background-color:red;
}

.news_post:nth-child(2)
{
   background-color:green;
}

.news_post:nth-child(3)
{
   background-color:black;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24SSd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try pseudo class.

```
.news_post:first-child
.news_post:last-child
```

**[More about](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)** pseudo classes in css

Comment: What about the second div?

Comment: Yes, even I've the same question. What to in case of divs between first and last div?

Comment: It is an example how to use pseudo classes. I am not writing the exact answer for him. Let him go through it and it gives practical idea

Comment: `I am not writing the exact answer for him` - Well, if you're attempting to answer a question, better to do it the complete way instead of giving a part of it and expecting the rest to be searched upon.